# How to use a service imported forRoot() in a feature module?

Tags: angular

I am using this package: https://github.com/troyanskiy/ng2-resource-rest but I could not figure out how to import it correctly for my feature modules. Doc says:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ResourceModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Ok. How can I use it in my feature module from here? I have a core module and a shared module as well. I have a `MyResource` class extending the `Resource` class from this package. When I try to inject and use `MyResource` in a feature module, angular says `No provider for MyResource`. If I add `MyResource` to feature module providers then it says`http` is undefined in the `Resource` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I also had to inject whatever Resource needs inside the extending class and provide the extending class for the shared module or the feature module itself.